# Velocity Template resource images

Tags: velocity

I have a spring configured web application and am using velocity engine and ITextRenderer to generate a PDF file. In my src/main/resources I have both my .vm file as well as a image file that I would like to display in the PDF. How do I go about referencing this image file in my .vm template so it will display in my PDF document when its generated.

Ive tried the html code:

```
img src="image.jpg"
```

and:

```
img src="src/main/resources/image.jpg" etc
```

None of this works. I am hoping to embed this image so I don't have to have the web server configured with a published images directory.

How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

HTML looks for images in the web context, not from the classpath.

(Hopefully it's obvious using a Maven source path couldn't possibly work.)

Images need to be in the `webapp` Maven directory, so Maven can package them into the war.

If your images will be changing/etc. then images should live *outside* the webapp altogether, and be streamed back via a servlet or controller.